# Handle Stripe response in Express app

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm trying to write a simple Stripe integration using Express.  My code creates the customer and charge and completes, appearing in my dashboard.  However I'm struggling to understand how to handle the response from Stripe.  The following just outputs the whole response from Stripe - what I would like is to be able to output a friendly message dependent on the content of this response:

```
stripe.customers.create({
    card: stripeToken
  })
  .then(customer =>
stripe.charges.create({
  amount: fee,
  description: "Client Ref: " + clientref,
  currency: "gbp",
  customer: customer.id,
  metadata: {
    'allocation:': allocate
  }
}))
  .then(charge => response.send(charge))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Error:", err);
    response.status(500).send({error: "Purchase Failed"});
  });
```

How can I look at the response and handle it accordingly?  I've tried using the response.send promise and I can get it to display parts of the response, but is this a 'charge' page?  How can I display this as html and not just plaintext??

I have looked in the Stripe docs and haven't found anything similar.  I want to be able to account for failed payments, declines etc as well as successful charges.

Any help or other examples much appreciated!

Thanks

edit: ok I handle the 'errors' in the catch block.  I didn't realise Stripe doesn't throw exceptions, so that makes life easier.  My point about formatting the messages still stands however. '/charge' just outputs plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I look at the response and handle it accordingly?

The Stripe docs clearly show you what the response for a successful charge is here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_charge (under `Example response`). It gives you back a large JSON object.

You need to figure out what part of that response is useful to you to display in your client-side application. If none of the information is needed, then you can simply ignore the response.

> (...) but is this a 'charge' page? How can I display this as html and not just plaintext??

What you are doing now is simply sending the whole JSON object to your client via `res.send`. And you are not doing anything with the response other than simply sending it back as plain text. You need to configure your view to display the response: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Or if your producing an API for others to consume, then use `res.json` to send back the JSON you got back from Stripe. http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json

> I want to be able to account for failed payments, declines etc as well as successful charges.

Then you need to handle the error that occurs. You are handling the error via `.catch`, but you aren't *inspecting* the error object. Again, the stripe have documentation on errors as well: https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors

And they even tell you how to handle errors as well: https://stripe.com/docs/api#handling-errors

Comment: Yes - if you had read my edit, you would see I have looked further at error handling.  You are correct though, this is in the docs.  I missed it!

I did look into Pug several weeks ago but will get back onto it now.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: I'd like to add to this - you state above "What you are doing now is simply sending the whole JSON object to your client via res.send" - my confusion is that 'send' in this context is to my client i.e. my browser.  I was under the impression that it was 'sending' back to Stripe hence why I couldn't figure out quite what was going on.  Your answer has helped immensely!

Comment: Oh I see your confusion. Be sure to refer to the Express docs for anything `req.*` or `res.*`: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html

Comment: Ok so I now have error handling and templating using Pug working.  Many thanks for your help Francisco!